# some attributes some shown in DOM tree but still working

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

New to meteor , I am using meteor.js to create a simple project like [this](http://demosimple.meteor.com/) 
I used  `<input value="{{counter}}" />` to create this input box showing value consistent with the paragraph.And it is working fine as you see.

However as I check the DOM tree in dev tools of chrome, I see `<input>` instead of `<input value="1">` as  I supposed it would be.

Why is the attribute value invisible here in DOM tree?Meanwhile,Can someone explain why I can see the number in input box even though I can't find the value attribute in DOM tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Meteor packages all your template's js and html files in the same javascript file at build time. 
Then the DOM is manipulated through javascript only. And lots of changes made to DOM elements through javascript do not show up in browser's consoles. For example, try to change an element's data attribute with jQuery `data()` and you won't see any new `data-...` attribute, same if you change your input's value by typing `$('input').val('some value')` in the console, the value will change but the `value` attribute won't show up.

If you open the console in your example (assuming that you are using Chrome, press F12) and switch to "Sources" and then open the only js file named '36dcbdf8917964892be8bca43c71d137318461f5.js' you will see that the value of the `input` is set through javascript (at line 82):

```
... 
HTML.INPUT({value:function(){return Spacebars.mustache(e.lookup("counter"))}})
...
```